# Desire2Learn Notifications - Are they email & SMS only, or can notifications be sent via other channels?

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I'm doing some feasibility work for a mobile app. We'd like to send D2L notifications directly to the mobile app (not via SMS or email).

We'd like to know if D2L's notifications system only notifies via email or SMS, or is it possible to configure it to send notifications via other channels, such as a message broker, ESB, etc.?

I've read D2L online doco; it's not clear if the system can be configured for anything other than email or SMS delivery. If it is only email/SMS, is it possible to use the REST API to get notifications for a student? That way we could have the app 'poll' for notifications.

Thanks,

Tim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The D2L learning platform as delivered currently can only deliver notifications to SMS or Email endpoints. It may be possible to expand the list of endpoints available through a customization services engagement with D2L. The Learning Framework API does not currently provide any direct access to the notifications themselves, only to the association between message types and endpoints.